# Check rar or zip for password protection by command line

Tags: winrar

I make scripts with Autohotkey. One of my hotkeys will check all selected zips or rars and should detect which of them are password protected, so as to isolated or rename them. Is there any command line with Winrar or with any other tool that can tell me this? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question on superuser.com to get a more competent answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
D:>unrar vt test.rar

UNRAR 5.30 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2015 Alexander Roshal

Archive: test.rar
Details: RAR 4

        Name: test.txt
        Type: File
        Size: 5712
 Packed size: 1168
       Ratio: 20%
       mtime: 2017-06-16 21:37:23,257
  Attributes: ..A....
       CRC32: 499EFFFA
     Host OS: Windows
 Compression: RAR 3.0(v29) -m3 -md=128K
       Flags: encrypted
```

But if the file names are encrypted too, it'll wait for the password:

```
D:\>unrar vt test.rar

UNRAR 5.30 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2015 Alexander Roshal

Enter password (will not be echoed) for test.rar:
Program aborted
```

Use this command to suppress the password prompt:

```
D:\>unrar vt -p- test.rar

UNRAR 5.30 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2015 Alexander Roshal

Checksum error in the encrypted file test.rar. Corrupt file or wrong password.
Archive: test.rar
Details: RAR 4, encrypted headers
```

The same technique is applicable for other archives. Find a basic CLI tool used to extract them and list the available parameters to find out which is used to show specific archive information.

Comment: Its the best answer about checking for:

Сheck rar is encrypted command. (check if rar file has password-protection command)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer below shows how to extract `rar` file, so i will answer about how to check `zip`

If you want to
check zip is encrypted archive

you better use `7z` ([like described here](https://supportex.net/blog/2011/08/bash-check-zip-rar-file-password-protection/)):

```
7z l -slt test_archive_with_password.zip
```

You will catch output information:

```
Encrypted = +
```

Example of output

```
    7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
    p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,12 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz (906EA),ASM,AES-NI)

    Scanning the drive for archives:
    1 file, 7898 bytes (8 KiB)

    Listing archive: /tmp/test_archive_with_password.zip

    --
    Path = /tmp/test_archive_with_password.zip
    Type = 7z
    Physical Size = 7898
    Headers Size = 154
    Method = LZMA2:48k 7zAES
    Solid = -
    Blocks = 1

    ----------
    Path = test.rtf
    Size = 44285
    Packed Size = 7744
    Modified = 2020-06-17 19:56:06
    Attributes = A
    CRC = 5BEEB5BE
    Encrypted = +
    Method = LZMA2:48k 7zAES:19
    Block = 0

    ...
```